# Camunda. Retry Service Task. Many different time intervals

Tags: camunda

can I configure for “retry time cycle” many different interval expression for example

something like that: “R6/PT10S, R2/PT30M” - 6 times each 10 Seconds and then 2 times after 30 minutes

Thanks in Advance,
Wladi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [job executor section of the camunda user guide](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/user-guide/process-engine/the-job-executor/#retry-intervals) only shows an example of comma separated intervals without repeats.

Looking at the code it seems a repeat is only recognized if there is a single interval configured

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/7.13.0/engine/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/util/ParseUtil.java#L88

The lookup of which interval to apply also does not consider any repeats

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/7.13.0/engine/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/cmd/DefaultJobRetryCmd.java#L113

This sounds like a useful feature though, you might want to open an issue in the [camunda issue tracker](https://jira.camunda.com/projects/CAM).